# python - Getting error while taking difference between two dates in columns

Tags: python, numpy

this is my code, I am trying to get business days between two dates
the number of days is saved in a new column 'nd'

```
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods=26,freq='D'),columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2020-02-01',periods=26,freq='D'),columns=['B'])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)


# Iterate over each row of the DataFrame
for index , row in df.iterrows():
    bc = np.busday_count(row['A'],row['B'])
    df['nd'] = bc
```

I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 35, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in busday_count
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Is there a way to fix it or another way to get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

busday_count only accepts dates, not datetimes change

```
bc = np.busday_count(row['A'],row['B'])
```

to

```
np.busday_count(row['A'].date(), row['B'].date())
```